# How to get Cypress coverage code of the main code from another repo?

Tags: reactjs, cypress, cypress-code-coverage

I have a repo of the main code and then there's a second repo just for E2E Cypress tests. How can I get the code coverage of the main code from the repo of Cypress tests ?

I tried the documentation of Cypress and I'm stuck at the instrumentation step. It doesn't cover my case which is separate repositories. Is there is a way to get this done ?

Comment: The instrumentation needs to be applied to the React project. Can you show how you are currently applying it?

Comment: I added the babel-plugin-istanbul to the .baberc file but still think something is missing to link the main code to the repo of e2e tests.

Comment: Not sure where you've done that, but broadly instrumentation needs to be done on the app code before running the app for testing purposes.